# Polymer 1.0 observer issue on paths using paper-toggle-button inside a dom-repeate

Tags: polymer, observers

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qonrthk1/6/

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-styles/color.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-styles/default-theme.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-behaviors/paper-inky-focus-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-checked-element-behavior/iron-checked-element-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-shadow-flex-layout.html">

<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/libiron-a11y-keys-behavior/iron-a11y-keys-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-behaviors/iron-button-state.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-icons/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/iron-selectable.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/iron-selection.html">

<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-item/paper-item-shared-styles.html">

<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.3/lib/paper-button-behavior/paper-button-behavior.html">


<dom-module id="pingo-toggle">
<style>
    .line {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .line span {
        margin-left: 24px;
    }
</style>
<template>


    <div class="line">
        <paper-toggle-button checked={{_working.data}}></paper-toggle-button>
        <span>{{_working.label}}</span>
        <span>{{computeBooleanToString(_working.data)}}</span>
    </div>
    <paper-item>{{_workingItem}}</paper-item>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_toArray(_notWorking)}}">
        <div class="line">
            <paper-toggle-button checked={{item.value.data.checked}}></paper-toggle-button>
            <span>{{item.value.label}}</span>
            <span>{{item.value.id}}</span>
            <span>{{computeBooleanToString(item.value.data.checked)}}</span>
        </div>
    </template>
    <paper-item>{{_notWorkingItem}}</paper-item>

</template>

<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is: 'pingo-toggle',
            properties: {
                _workingItem: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "placeholder"
                },
                _notWorkingItem: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "placeholder"
                },
                _working: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true,
                    value: {
                        label: "Working Toggle",
                        data: true
                    }
                },
                _notWorking: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true,
                    value: {
                        a: {
                            checked: true
                        },
                        b: {
                            checked: false
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            _newItemObserved: function (newValue, oldValue) {
                this._value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newValue));
            },
            // Observers
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            observers: ['_notWorkingValueChanged(_notWorking.*)', '_workingValueChanged(_working.*)'],
            // Smart check. only fire if we change state.
            _workingValueChanged: function (changeRecord) {
                var thisElement = this;

                this._workingItem = this.computeBooleanToString(this._working.data) + Math.random();
                console.log("Working" + changeRecord.path);

            },
            _notWorkingValueChanged: function (changeRecord) {
                var thisElement = this;

                this._notWorkingItem = "_notWorkingItem fired" + Math.random();

                console.log("notWorking:" + changeRecord.path);

            },
            computeBooleanToString: function (a) {
                return a === true ? 'true' : 'false';
            },
            _toArray: function (obj) {
                var index = 0;
                var thisElement = this;
                this._arrayData = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
                    var id = "item_" + index;
                    ++index;
                    var val = {};
                    val.data = obj[key];
                    val.label = "hi:" + key;
                    val.data = obj[key];
                    val.id = id;
                    val.original = obj.key;
                    return {
                        name: key,
                        value: val
                    };
                });
                return this._arrayData;
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

The problem I am seeing is that when I have a dom-repeater, where I convert an object to an array, it doesn't seem to bind properly to the paper-toggle-button value.
In my jsFiddle, you can see a working simple paper-toggle-button, and on that isn't working when inside the repeater.

***Goal***: I am try to detect toggle changes that happen inside the dom-repeater.

***Expected***: I expected the this._notWorking.a.checked and this._notWorking.b.checked to be changed upon a toggle.

My observers
   observers: ['_notWorkingValueChanged(_notWorking.*)', '_workingValueChanged(_working.*)'],

The _notWorkingValueChanged never gets triggered.

The example is pretty small, so hopefully its an obvious problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Move the computed value for `_notWorking` out of your `dom-repeat`:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_notWorking}}">
```

And add it to your property definition:

```
_notWorking: {
    type: Object,
    notify: true,
    value: function() {
      return this._toArray({
        a: { checked: true },
        b: { checked: false }
    }); }
},
```

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate on what the differences are between this and what I had?  On the surface mine appears to look like it should have worked.

Comment: As far as I know, Polymer `dom-repeat` doesn't support a computed binding for `items` because it expects an Array (confirmed in Polymer source). The fact that the computed binding worked initially is a side-effect of computed bindings in general. However, when trying to manage updates, Polymer has no object reference when the template was stamped out with a computed binding.

Comment: Ricky, thanks for the help on this.  I have another similar problem, based upon this stuff, where I do have proof of object reference and observation is not firing.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898959/polymer-1-0-observers-watching-a-object-path-is-not-triggering-even-though-data